# Getting modified values from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with the required values. After editing a cell, if I use table.getvalue(row,column), I get the previous unaltered values. But if I select another cell before clicking the save button I get the modified values. Can anyone help me to remove this problem??

PS: I have not yet added any actionlisteners for the table

Comment: Add the code you tried with

Comment: @user3145272 Please show you code.

Answer (score 1):

The default update mechanism only changes the model when the cell editor loses the focus. Either tabbing out of the cell or clicking in a different cell will cause the vital "focus lost" event which triggers the model change

You could add an `ActionListener` (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). It will get triggered when you press RETURN. In the handler, call fireEditingStopped() to trigger the "copy to model" code (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor).

or add following code to your table,

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).

> Every table object uses a table model object to manage the actual table data. A table model object must implement the TableModel interface. If the programmer does not provide a table model object, JTable automatically creates an instance of DefaultTableModel.
>
> A table model can have a set of listeners that are notified whenever the table data changes. Listeners are instances of [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

int row=table.getSelectedRow();
int column=table.getSelectedColumn();

table.getValue(row,Column)

If Yes you need to use [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)